# Player survives if generated number < previous number. Probability of Alice winning the game

Tags: probability

Alice, Bob and Carol are playing a game. Each round they press a number, which generates a random number independently uniformly distributed between $[0,1]$. If the number generated by this player is smaller than the smallest number so far, the player survives. Otherwise they get eliminated. They play in turns, i.e. Alice goes first, then Bob, then Carol, then Alice again etc.

What's the probability that Alice eventually wins this game?

Consider we independently sample $n$ times, the probability that $x_1$ is the smallest is $\frac{1}{n}$, that's the probability that Alice survives after $n$th round.

But how do we find the probability that Alice out-survive the rest of the players?

If there are two players, Alice and Bob, the answer is trivial. But somehow from two to three makes all the difference..

Comment: @jlammy yes, just edited to clarify

Comment: To clarify: If Alice gets $0.4$ and Bob gets $0.7$, Bob is out. It is Carol's turn. To survive, does Carol's number need to be below $0.4$ or below $0.7$?

Comment: did someone simulate this so I can check my solution? :)

Comment: @paw88789 sorry, it has to be below 0.4. i.e. the last surviving player's number. i have edited the question to be more clear

Comment: do you know the numerical answer? or an approximation of the answer?

Comment: From simulating $10\:000\:000$ games, I find the likelihood that a particular ranking is achieved. (X, Y, Z) here denotes the event that X is the surviving player, Y is the last eliminated player, and Z is the first eliminated player.
\begin{align*}
(Alice, Bob, Carol) &: 6.99\%, \\
(Alice, Carol, Bob) &: 39.66\% \\
(Bob, Alice, Carol) &: 27.07\%, \\
(Bob, Carol, Alice) &: 2.14\%, \\
(Carol, Alice, Bob) &: 13.68\%, \\
(Carol, Bob, Alice) &: 10.46\%. \end{align*}

Comment: what do you get for p(alice wins)? with more digits :P

Comment: @PeterMüller With more digits:
\begin{align*}
(Alice, Bob, Carol) &: 6.99318\%, \\
(Alice, Carol, Bob) &: 39.66269\% \\
(Bob, Alice, Carol) &: 27.06544\%, \\
(Bob, Carol, Alice) &: 2.14123\%, \\
(Carol, Alice, Bob) &: 13.67994\%, \\
(Carol, Bob, Alice) &: 10.45752\%. \end{align*} So the probability that Alice wins is around $46.65587\%$.

Comment: ahh I see, the calc I made has a small error, i got 0.46490... I was under counting a bit... glad I didn't post :P

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be the number of surviving rounds before the first eliminating round, and $b$ be the number of surviving rounds between the two eliminating rounds. Thus the game ends in $a + b + 2$ rounds. We consider the probability of this situation happening.

If we generate $a + b + 2$ random numbers, then their order take equal probability $\frac 1{(a + b + 2)!}$ for each possible permutation. Among all $(a + b + 2)!$ such permutations, only $a(a + b + 1)$ of them correspond to the situation above, namely the $(a + 1)$-th number can be inserted anywhere before the smallest of the first $a$ numbers, and the $(a + b + 2)$-th number can be inserted anywhere before the smallest of the first $(a + b + 1)$ numbers.

This means that the probability that one player gets eliminated on the $(a + 1)$-th round and another player gets eliminated on the $(a + b + 2)$-th round is equal to $\frac{a(a + b + 1)}{(a + b + 2)!}$.

It is clear that A survives to the end if and only if we are in one of the following two cases:

- $a \equiv 1 \pmod 3, b \equiv 0 \pmod 2$;
- $a \equiv 2 \pmod 3, b \equiv 1 \pmod 2$.

Therefore the final answer is equal to $$\sum_{a \equiv 1 \pmod 3}\sum_{b \equiv 0 \pmod 2} \frac{a(a + b + 1)}{(a + b + 2)!} + \sum_{a \equiv 2 \pmod 3}\sum_{b \equiv 1 \pmod 2} \frac{a(a + b + 1)}{(a + b + 2)!}.$$

It is approximately equal to $0.46649280488530$.

Comment: Thanks. this seems to really dependent on that there are 3 players. what if there are 4? or more? ....

Comment: It's the same analysis. If there are $4$ players, then you may write $a, b, c$ for the number of surviving rounds, and find those triples $a, b, c$ which correspond to the survival of A. For each $a, b, c$, the probability would be $\frac{a(a + b + 1)(a + b + c + 2)}{(a + b + c + 3)!}$.

Comment: very interesting. just lastly. it seems like this solution has nothing to do with distribution? i.e. the numbers drawn don't have to be [0,1] uniformly distributed?

Comment: You are right, the numbers can be arbitrarily distributed, as long as it is not "concentrated" on any point, i.e. $\Bbb P(X = x) = 0$ for any $x \in \Bbb R$.